# sys.exit() triggers TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() error

Tags: python

I can not make my script stop. I've tried sys.exit () as well as os._exit()

I have a bit of the code:

```
try:

        report  = func_timeout(config.timeout_time, load_the_report, args=(download_id, config))

    except FunctionTimedOut: 
        print(f"timeout error for the {config.name} {config.date}")
        print('####')
        sys.exit()
```

sys.exit () gives an error :

```
SystemExit: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in showtraceback(self, exc_tuple, filename, tb_offset, exception_only, running_compiled_code)
   2055                     stb = ['An exception has occurred, use %tb to see '
   2056                            'the full traceback.\n']
-> 2057                     stb.extend(self.InteractiveTB.get_exception_only(etype,
   2058                                                                      value))
   2059                 else:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in get_exception_only(self, etype, value)
    752         value : exception value
    753         """
--> 754         return ListTB.structured_traceback(self, etype, value)
    755 
    756     def show_exception_only(self, etype, evalue):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, context)
    627             chained_exceptions_tb_offset = 0
    628             out_list = (
--> 629                 self.structured_traceback(
    630                     etype, evalue, (etb, chained_exc_ids),
    631                     chained_exceptions_tb_offset, context)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1365         else:
   1366             self.tb = tb
-> 1367         return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
   1368             self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1369 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1265         if mode in self.verbose_modes:
   1266             # Verbose modes need a full traceback
-> 1267             return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
   1268                 self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
   1269             )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in structured_traceback(self, etype, evalue, etb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
   1122         """Return a nice text document describing the traceback."""
   1123 
-> 1124         formatted_exception = self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context,
   1125                                                                tb_offset)
   1126 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in format_exception_as_a_whole(self, etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
   1080 
   1081 
-> 1082         last_unique, recursion_repeat = find_recursion(orig_etype, evalue, records)
   1083 
   1084         frames = self.format_records(records, last_unique, recursion_repeat)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py in find_recursion(etype, value, records)
    380     # first frame (from in to out) that looks different.
    381     if not is_recursion_error(etype, value, records):
--> 382         return len(records), 0
    383 
    384     # Select filename, lineno, func_name to track frames with

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

os._exit() worked but it does not print at what line the timeout happened

if I am not quitting the script it errors further, where the report is meant to be created (missing variable). I don't know what is wrong with this

Comment: I don't see a `TypeError` in the traceback.

Comment: @Matthias sorry I missed a part, edited my post